# Which are best option(s) to append many props to child component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

Using `react 15.5.4`

I have a component already configured to cross `props` in its child.

```js
export default class Component extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <TemplateAbout
        header={{
         title: 'WHY US',
         description: 'Our Team Member share the same Vision',
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

I want to change the interface of the `Component` into `NewComponent` as the example below.

```
export default class NewComponent extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <TemplateAbout>
        <Header title="WHY US" description="Our Team Member share the same Vision" />
      </TemplateAbout>
    );
  }
}
```

Which are best ways to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the object spread syntax to pass props in JSX. It will be combined with the rest of the props.

```
 render() {
    const header = {
      title: 'WHY US',
      description: 'Our Team Member share the same Vision',
    }
    return (
      <TemplateAbout>
        <Header otherProps="otherValue" {...header} />
      </TemplateAbout>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I didn't understand what you really want to achieve, if you need the individual props to syntactically be passed one-by-one, I don't think there's easy way to do it.

Comment: I would say that using a `getChildContext` from `TemplateAbout` and a `contextType` in each child of TemplateAbout could do it. You might have to re-render all the children every time the `getChildContext` change return a different object. (To be Confirmed, maybe  `componentWillUpdate` have a context equivalent). @EvanSebastian is this the hard way you are thinking of?

Comment: If `Header` in question is illustrative and the children of `<TemplateAbout />`  is computed/passed as props, then yeah, child context is one way to pass the props implicitly as context, though `React.Children.map` might be better in this case.

Comment: it's work well with `React.Children.map` but why not use `getChildContext`, which one have the best performance ?